# How to empty the ImageURL when using picasso?

Tags: java, android

Basically, my main motive is to choose/remove the imageURL where the image is chosen from the gallery and showed in Imageview. The first phase is working fine i.e. choosing the image. But the problem is when I try to remove the image while removing the image I also need to make that variable empty which is storing the image path.

The imageurl which is the path of the image when it is choosed is stored in the variable named as "mImageUri".

```
//code to set the Image in Imageview using Imageurl
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE){
        mImageUri = data.getData();

        Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);
    }
}

public void remove_image(View view) {
    //code to empty the imageuri
    `enter code here`
   //please suggest me the code to solve this problem or any link which will help me out.
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear image use

```
mImageUri = null;
mImageView.setImageResource(0)
```

Comment: `remove_image(View view)` is called?

Comment: I don't need to set empty the imageview rather I need to empty the image url stored in mImageUri.

Comment: `mImageUri = null;` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! sometimes it happens to you that you are so close to the answer and you have tried all logical best way to do it but never try the basic one.